# SharePoint Online search duplicate results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

In SharePoint Online, when I use the search bar, all results are displayed twice in the "All" vertical.
Do you know why and how the correct this ?

Example below:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... Looks like a bug. I'd try to reindex a couple of sites (Site settings -> Search and Offline Availability -> Reindex site) -
and if it still continues - maybe it's a ticket to Microsoft support.